# how to rotate text Especially in ie8?

Tags: jquery, html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/manojivasan/hdr28m78/

I need text to be rotate, Especially i need it in IE8, Except IE8 Other browsers i am getting,
can any one help me in this issue

```
   .Tips a {
    color: #82C739;
    text-decoration: none;
    } 
   .Tips {
    color: blue;
    font-size: 10px;
    width: 200px;
    line-height: 12px;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=-7);
    /*-ms-filter:filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=-7);*/
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this website to convert your css3 rotate codes to IE Matrix.

http://www.useragentman.com/IETransformsTranslator/

#transformedObject {

```
 /* IE8+ - must be on one line, unfortunately */ 
 -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=0.992546151641322, M12=0.12186934340514763, M21=-0.12186934340514763, M22=0.992546151641322, SizingMethod='auto expand')";

 /* IE6 and 7 */ 
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(
          M11=0.992546151641322,
          M12=0.12186934340514763,
          M21=-0.12186934340514763,
          M22=0.992546151641322,
          SizingMethod='auto expand');


 /*
  * To make the transform-origin be the middle of
  * the object.    Note: These numbers
  * are approximations.  For more accurate results,
  * use Internet Explorer with this tool.
  */
 margin-left: -6px; 
 margin-top: -16px;
```

}